# Блоки инициализации

Tags: java

Почему выполнится без ошибок?

```
public class Test{

static{
   int x = 5;
}

static int x = 5;

}
```

Comment: а какое по-вашему должно быть исключение и почему?

Comment: Может, я неправильно понимаю слово "перекрывает", но, насколько я заметил, в блоке инициализации просто нет смысла создавать переменные, поскольку:

    public class Tester{
        static
        {
            int x = 5;
        }
        //static int x = 6;
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(x);   // ошибка компиляции
            System.out.println(Tester.x); //ошибка компиляции
        }
    } 

Но если раскомментировать `static int x = 6;`, то вместо ошибки компиляции в двух случаях выведет `6`.

Comment: @romashechka, зубрите учебник по теме области видимости переменных

Comment: хорошо, но какие опровержение данного примера?

Comment: Это две абсолютно разные переменные - они могут быть даже разных типов:
    
    public class Test {
     static {
      String x = "5";
     }
     static int x = 6;
    }

Comment: Статический блок инициализации - это обычный метод. Он не служит для объявления переменных уровня класса. Но в нем можно поместить довольно сложную логику инициализации, в которой могут понадобиться локальные переменные.

Comment: когда минусуют, лучше решение запоминается

Answer (score 4):

Здесь нет кода, который мог бы выбросить исключение. Видимо, вас интересует, почему это компилируется.

Все просто: у вас статическая переменная `Test.x` и один статический инициализатор с локальной переменной `x`, которая в силу свой локальности "перекрывает" переменную `Test.x`.

Вот аналогичный случай:

```
public class Test {
    static int x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x = 5;  
        System.out.println("x = " + x); // Используется Test.x
        int x;
        x = 10;  
        System.out.println("x = " + x); // Используется локальная переменная x
        System.out.println("Test.x = " + Test.x); // Используется Test.x
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
x = 5 
x = 10
Test.x = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

А ещё можно так написать, присвоение до объявления.

```
class Main{
   static {
        x = 5;
   }
   static int x;
}
```